# Magit: how to disable highlight in the selected diff hunk

Tags: git, emacs, highlight, magit

I'm using emacs 27.2 and magit 20210406.454. When I show a diff on magit (i.g., on magit-diff) the selected whole hunk is highlighted. How can I disable it?

For example, this is the screen capture when I show the diff on magit:

[image: Not selected hunk]

It shows added lines in green and removed lines in red, which is good. However when I move the cursor to the first hunk, the color of added lines is changed to blue:

[image: Selected the first hunk]

The current line is highlighted in yellow. Also, when I move the cursor to the next hunk that has both added lines and removed lines, the color of those lines are changed:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to disable highlighting only on added lines and removed lines (i.e., keeping showing those lines in greed and red) while keeping showing the current line in yellow. Is that possible?

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem. please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That helps future visitors who might have the same (or similar) question to find out what answer(s) have helped in the past. Even if the answer has not completely answered the question (and so you might be disinclined to accept it), upvoting  helpful answers (and downvoting harmful ones) helps those future visitors to figure out which answers might be helpful to them. For more information, please click on the `?` icon in the upper right and read the overview of how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to edit the relevant faces from here:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `magit-faces` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You'll likely spot them based on the displayed examples in that buffer.

Also note that magit may defer to `diff-mode` faces for some things, so it might also be useful to look at:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `diff-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I think the faces you're looking for will be:

- `magit-diff-added-highlight`
- `magit-diff-removed-highlight`

In addition you may or may not care about:

- `magit-diff-base-highlight`
- `magit-diff-context-highlight`
- `magit-diff-file-heading-highlight`
- `magit-diff-hunk-heading-highlight`
- `magit-diff-our-highlight`
- `magit-diff-their-highlight`

For the ones you don't want to vary contextually, you can make the
face *inherit* from the equivalent non-`highlight` face.

Comment: Editing magit-faces and diff-mode worked! Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that you can 'accept' an answer when it solves your issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.